# Windows 10 Audit Mode - Remote desktop does not work

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, sysprep, windows-audit-mode

I am in the process of building a customized image for our developers.  I have a virtual machine set up with windows 10 on it, and was hoping that I could enable Remote Desktop connections and allow a developer to go in and install everything.  For some reason, even with Remote Desktop enabled, the firewall completely turned off, TermSrvs running, I cannot get Remote Desktop to even connect to the virtual machine.

Does anyone know if Windows 10 Audit Mode disables Remote Desktop from working?

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1463417-windows-10-audit-mode-with-remote-desktop-enabled

Comment: The error is the standard one you would get if the machine was offline or remote desktop is disabled.  I tried both IP address and computer name.  Neither one worked.  I also tried unchecking the Network Level Authentication setting.

Comment: Let's start with the basic stuff: can you DNS lookup the machine (nslookup), ping the machine, telnet on port 3389? If you can't do these, it's not a Remote Desktop problem, but a something else problem.

Comment: I won't be able to do DNS lookup, as it is actually behind a firewall, however I have enabled port forwarding for port 3389.  Even after creating that firewall rule, I can't telnet in on that port.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly, but DNS should be working even if the machine is behind a firewall because Remote Desktop requires a direct line of sight between the machines (unless you use a gateway to proxy your connection).

Comment: So here is what is happening.  I have a SME server inside our Domain that acts as a firewall/router for my machines that I use to create MDT images.  I am trying to enable the ability for someone to use remote desktop to connect to one of those machines from the domain.  Because it is inside the SME server's network, DNS shouldn't work